# не запускается сервер payara

Tags: java, spring-security, payara

Проект на Spring-boot пока еще пустой
вот помник:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>ru.javabegin.library</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-library</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>my-library</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <slf4j-api.version>1.7.30</slf4j-api.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
<!--         исключаем Tomcat, т.к. мы используем GlassFish-->
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>-->
<!--            <scope>provided</scope>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.22.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j-api.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>30.0-jre</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax/javaee-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

сервер TomCat запустился без проблем (появляется окно ввода пароля)
Подключил к проекту cервер Payara, но при запуске он выдает

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.security.KeyStoreException: JCEKS not found
```

вот полный трейс:

```
[2020-11-10T19:33:35.123+0300] [Payara 5.2020.5] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00015] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=24 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1605025988482] [timeMillis: 1605026015123] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Shutdown requested
MultiException stack 1 of 2
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.security.KeyStoreException: JCEKS not found
    at org.glassfish.security.services.impl.JCEKSPasswordAliasStore.containsKey(JCEKSPasswordAliasStore.java:169)
    at fish.payara.nucleus.microprofile.config.source.PasswordAliasConfigSource.getValue(PasswordAliasConfigSource.java:100)
    at fish.payara.nucleus.microprofile.config.spi.PayaraConfig.getSourceValue(PayaraConfig.java:183)
    at fish.payara.nucleus.microprofile.config.spi.PayaraConfig.getValueConverted(PayaraConfig.java:166)
    at fish.payara.nucleus.microprofile.config.spi.PayaraConfig.lambda$getValue$1(PayaraConfig.java:161)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.compute(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1853)
    at fish.payara.nucleus.microprofile.config.spi.PayaraConfig.getValue(PayaraConfig.java:157)
    at fish.payara.nucleus.microprofile.config.spi.PayaraConfig.getValueInternal(PayaraConfig.java:127)
    at fish.payara.nucleus.microprofile.config.spi.PayaraConfig.getOptionalValue(PayaraConfig.java:123)
    at fish.payara.microprofile.healthcheck.HealthCheckService.postConstruct(HealthCheckService.java:146)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.invoke(ReflectionHelper.java:1268)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:309)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:351)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:463)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:281)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:65)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2102)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:93)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:67)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1213)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1144)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.security.KeyStoreException: JCEKS not found
    at org.glassfish.security.services.impl.JCEKSPasswordAliasStore.pa(JCEKSPasswordAliasStore.java:103)
    at org.glassfish.security.services.impl.JCEKSPasswordAliasStore.containsKey(JCEKSPasswordAliasStore.java:167)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.security.KeyStoreException: JCEKS not found
    at java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:851)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.store.PasswordAdapter.loadKeyStore(PasswordAdapter.java:131)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.store.PasswordAdapter.<init>(PasswordAdapter.java:110)
    at org.glassfish.security.services.impl.JCEKSPasswordAliasStore.pa(JCEKSPasswordAliasStore.java:101)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: JCEKS KeyStore not available
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:159)
    at java.security.Security.getImpl(Security.java:695)
    at java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:848)
    ... 31 more
MultiException stack 2 of 2
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: post construct on fish.payara.microprofile.healthcheck.HealthCheckService
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:369)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:463)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:281)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:65)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2102)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:93)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:67)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1213)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1144)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
]]

[2020-11-10T19:33:35.156+0300] [Payara 5.2020.5] [SEVERE] [NCLS-CORE-00016] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=24 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1605025988482] [timeMillis: 1605026015156] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Startup service failed to start
MultiException stack 1 of 2
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.security.KeyStoreException: JCEKS not found
    at org.glassfish.security.services.impl.JCEKSPasswordAliasStore.containsKey(JCEKSPasswordAliasStore.java:169)
    at fish.payara.nucleus.microprofile.config.source.PasswordAliasConfigSource.getValue(PasswordAliasConfigSource.java:100)
    at fish.payara.nucleus.microprofile.config.spi.PayaraConfig.getSourceValue(PayaraConfig.java:183)
    at fish.payara.nucleus.microprofile.config.spi.PayaraConfig.getValueConverted(PayaraConfig.java:166)
    at fish.payara.nucleus.microprofile.config.spi.PayaraConfig.lambda$getValue$1(PayaraConfig.java:161)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.compute(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1853)
    at fish.payara.nucleus.microprofile.config.spi.PayaraConfig.getValue(PayaraConfig.java:157)
    at fish.payara.nucleus.microprofile.config.spi.PayaraConfig.getValueInternal(PayaraConfig.java:127)
    at fish.payara.nucleus.microprofile.config.spi.PayaraConfig.getOptionalValue(PayaraConfig.java:123)
    at fish.payara.microprofile.healthcheck.HealthCheckService.postConstruct(HealthCheckService.java:146)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.invoke(ReflectionHelper.java:1268)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:309)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:351)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:463)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:281)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:65)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2102)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:93)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:67)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1213)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1144)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.security.KeyStoreException: JCEKS not found
    at org.glassfish.security.services.impl.JCEKSPasswordAliasStore.pa(JCEKSPasswordAliasStore.java:103)
    at org.glassfish.security.services.impl.JCEKSPasswordAliasStore.containsKey(JCEKSPasswordAliasStore.java:167)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.security.KeyStoreException: JCEKS not found
    at java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:851)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.store.PasswordAdapter.loadKeyStore(PasswordAdapter.java:131)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.store.PasswordAdapter.<init>(PasswordAdapter.java:110)
    at org.glassfish.security.services.impl.JCEKSPasswordAliasStore.pa(JCEKSPasswordAliasStore.java:101)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: JCEKS KeyStore not available
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:159)
    at java.security.Security.getImpl(Security.java:695)
    at java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:848)
    ... 31 more
MultiException stack 2 of 2
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: post construct on fish.payara.microprofile.healthcheck.HealthCheckService
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:369)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:463)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:281)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:65)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2102)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:93)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:67)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1213)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1144)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
]]
```

в чем тут проблема?

Comment: похоже проблема не в Spring, попробовал сервер запустить отдельно, вылетает таже самая ошибка

Comment: почему ему именно JCEKS нужен, ведь в java по умолчанию JKS используется.
Тогда эта ошибка должна у все вылетать, тогда в сети было бы много обсуждений на эту тему.
Это где-то в настройках сервера прописывается?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема ушла после того как установил версию payara 5.201, версия jdk 11